# how to use command line in magento 2.1?

Tags: php, magento-2.0, magento-2.1, server-setup, command-line

I have tried to run the command line script in a linux VPS with PuTTy and get this error:

> Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.

I tried to update php to 7.0.5 but

- `phpinfo()` shows 7.0.5
- in PuTTy `php -v` shows php version 5.4.1

How to run command-line in my VPS?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have installed multiple versions of PHP and PHP-CLI uses a different version than the web server. Run `which php` to see to which executable "php" refers. How to change that depends on your operation system and how you installed PHP in the first place. But you can always use the PHP 7 binary directly, for example with `/usr/local/bin/php7`. For the real path, look at the phpinfo() output of your `info.php`.
2. Updating to PHP 7.0.5 would not help anyways. As you see in the error message, 7.0.3 to 7.0.5 are not supported, so if you use PHP 7, you should update to the latest version.